# Vimeo oembed issues with IE 8 & 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, vimeo, oembed

I am using Vimeo oembed on my site (without flash). I have the embedded video playing fine in all browsers, including IE 8 & 9. The issue is that when the Vimeo embedded code below is run it tries to access unload_moogaloop which wouldn't exist if I have no flash object. This is throwing a debug error in IE 8 & 9.

```
try { document.getElementById("flash-object").SetReturnValue(__flash__toXML(function(){window.onunload = function(){if (document.getElementById('flash-object').unload_moogaloop()) return document.getElementById('flash-object').unload_moogaloop()};}()) ); } catch (e) { document.getElementById("flash-object").SetReturnValue("<undefined/>"); }
```

Is there a way to ensure this embedded code does not run?